# Import csv to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

делаю импорт CSV файла вроде бы success, но русские слова не отображаются при выводе.
Значение NULL NULL NULL.

Код:
SET client_encoding = 'ISO_8859_5';
COPY for_telegramm FROM 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\tmp\test2.csv' (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, DELIMITER ';', ENCODING 'UTF8');

Comment: Попробуйте сменить кодировку на клиенте

Comment: Прошу прощения, где именно, на каком клиенте и как можно сделать и какую кодировку нужно указать

Comment: Вы подключаетесь с помощью клиента к серверу, у клиента кодировка SET client_encoding = 'ISO_8859_5. Это в ошибке написано. При новом подключении, для текущего сеанса попробуйте сменить кодировку этой же командой на UTF8